# Linear independence, yet Wronskian is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, wronskian

Why is the following set linearly independent for all x on ($-\infty$, $\infty$)?

$$\{1+x, 1-x, 1-3x\}$$

The Wronskian is $0$, but Wolfram Alpha says it is still linear independent?  Why is this?

Thanks!

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+%7B1-x%2C+1%2Bx%2C+1-3x%7D+linearly+independent%3F

Comment: $1-3x=2(1-x)-(1+x)$, so it isn't linearly independent. Not sure what WA is doing though.

Comment: Yah, that's what I got as well. I don't know why WA is saying that...

Comment: W|A is treating your input as a vector over $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $x$ as a constant.  Thus, it is seeing your input as a set containing one (non-zero) vector.

Comment: Ah, it is linear dependent:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear+independence+%28x%2C1-x%29%2C+%28x%2C1%2Bx%29%2C+%28x%2C1-3x%29

Thank you to anorton for explaining W|A's error, it was easily fixed!

Answer (score 4):

You have **three** polynomials of degree $1$ hence they cannot be linear independent.

Comment: Shouldn't a set of three polynomials of degree 1 be linear dependent?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Since the Wronskian is zero, no conclusion can be drawn about linear independence.

For linear independence, we want to go back to the basic definitions.

Can you proceed?

Comment: Yep, I went back and did the calculations for the coefficents (matrix, row reduction, etc) => If the lin comb is c1a1 + c2a2 + c3a3 = 0, then any c1 = k, c2 = -2k, c3 = k, should set them to zero....so I don't quite know............(If the set is {a1, a2, a3})

Comment: Be careful how WA is interpreting your vectors! My only point is that when the Wronskian is zero, you should always go back to the basic definition and you proved that they are linearly dependent.